# Volume Form induces Borel Measure Proof-Verification

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, differential-geometry

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold of positive dimension and $\omega$ a volume form on $M$. Suppose that $F \in
> \operatorname{Diff}(M)$ such that $F^*\omega = \omega$. Then there
>   exists a finite $F$-invariant regular Borel measure on
>   $M$.

*Proof.* Define $I \in (C^\infty(M))^*$ by
$$I(f) := \int_M f\omega.$$
Because $C^\infty(M)$ is dense in $C^0(M)$ under the sup-norm, $I$ extends uniquely to an element of $(C^0(M))^*$. By the Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique finite regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that 
$$I(f) = \int_M fd\mu$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$. Thus left to show is $F$-invariance, that is 
$$\mu(F^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$$ for all measurable $A \subseteq M$ or equivalently, $F_* \mu = \mu$, where $F_*\mu$ denotes the pushforward-measure of $\mu$ under $F$. By assumption, we have that 
$$I(f) = \int_M F^*(f\omega) = \int_M (f \circ F)\omega = I(f \circ F)$$ for all $f \in C^\infty(M)$ since $F^*\omega = \omega$ implies that $F$ is orientation-preserving. Thus also 
$$\int_M f d\mu = \int_M(f \circ F)d\mu$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$. The latter is exactly the integral 
$$\int_M f d(F_*\mu).$$ But then also $$I(f) = \int_M fd(F_*\mu)$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$ which implies by uniqueness that 
$$F_*\mu = \mu$$
because $F_*\mu$ is also regular as $\mu$ is.
$\square$

**Is that proof correct? Is there a simpler argument?**

Comment: Are you sure you got the statement right? The uniqueness claim you wrote down is false. For a simple counterexample, take $F$ to be the identity; then every Borel measure is $F^{-1}$-invariant. For a somewhat less trivial example, let $F\colon S^n\to S^n$ be the antipodal map, and let $\pi: S^n \to \mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ be the standard projection. Then for any arbitrary $n$-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$, the form $\pi^*\eta$ defines an $F^{-1}$-invariant Borel measure on $S^n$.

Comment: @JackLee Sure, you are totally right. I was thinking along the line *uniquely associated to the volume form $\omega$* because of the statement of the Riesz representation theorem. But then I would have to define what *associated* means in the statement...sigh.