# Volume form induces Borel measure: proof verification

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, solution-verification

**Disclaimer:** I asked this question already on the regular mathematics site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309725/volume-form-induces-borel-measure-proof-verification), but to no avail, even with a bounty. I think answering said question is still of value.

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold of positive dimension and $\omega$ a volume form on $M$. Suppose that $F \in
> \operatorname{Diff}(M)$ such that $F^*\omega = \omega$. Then there
>   exists a finite $F$-invariant regular Borel measure on
>   $M$.

*Proof.* Define $I \in (C^\infty(M))^*$ by
$$I(f) := \int_M f\omega.$$
Because $C^\infty(M)$ is dense in $C^0(M)$ under the sup-norm, $I$ extends uniquely to an element of $(C^0(M))^*$. By the Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique finite regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that 
$$I(f) = \int_M fd\mu$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$. Thus left to show is $F$-invariance, that is 
$$\mu(F^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$$ for all measurable $A \subseteq M$ or equivalently, $F_* \mu = \mu$, where $F_*\mu$ denotes the pushforward-measure of $\mu$ under $F$. By assumption, we have that 
$$I(f) = \int_M f\omega \overset{(\dagger) }{=} \int_M F^*(f\omega) = \int_M (f \circ F)\omega = I(f \circ F)$$ for all $f \in C^\infty(M)$ where $(\dagger) $ is justified since $F^*\omega = \omega$ implies that $F$ is orientation-preserving. Thus also 
$$\int_M f d\mu = \int_M(f \circ F)d\mu$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$. The latter is exactly the integral 
$$\int_M f d(F_*\mu).$$ But then also $$I(f) = \int_M fd(F_*\mu)$$ for all $f \in C^0(M)$ which implies by uniqueness that 
$$F_*\mu = \mu$$
because $F_*\mu$ is also regular as $\mu$ is.
$\square$

**Is that proof correct? Is there a simpler argument?**

Comment: Why do you need a line about orientation preserving? Other than that, I think the proof is fine, and cannot be simplified, essentially.

Comment: @erz Because otherwise we wouldn't have $$\int_M F^*(f\omega) = \int_M f\omega = I(f),$$ I think.

Comment: I don't get that line either. Don't you have
$$ I(f) = \int_M f\omega = \int_Mf F^*\omega =  \int_M F^*((f\circ F^{-1})\omega) = \int_M (f\circ F^{-1})\omega = I(f\circ F^{-1})$$

Comment: Orientation preservation is needed to make the step $$\int_MF^*(g\omega)=\int_{F(M)}g\omega=\int g\omega$$ I think.

Comment: @S.Surace Yes, exactly. I use the *diffeomorphism invariance* property on page 407 in Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds.

Comment: I forgot an $M$ in the last integral. But there is still something weird with $F$ and its inverse. I'm pretty sure that my first comment is correct in that there is an $F^{-1}$ in the identity for $I$. Then, I get
$$ \int_M f d\mu = \int_M(f\circ F^{-1})d\mu, \quad f\in C_0(M)$$
by taking limits, and then $$ \mu(F(A)) = \int_M\chi_{F(A)}d\mu = \int_M (\chi_A\circ F^{-1})d\mu = \int_M \chi_Ad\mu = \mu(A)$$. But this would show that $F^{-1}_*\mu=\mu$ and not what you initially claimed.

Comment: Still, it makes intuitive sense that when a pullback is converted to a pushforward, the direction of the map must also change.

Comment: Sorry, of course your claim is still correct because $F^{-1}_*\mu=\mu$ implies $F_*\mu=\mu$. :)

Comment: @S.Surace Yes, I guess we are both right since $\mu$ is $F$ as well as $F^{-1}$-invariant.